# Hibernate: Can't Delete | removing a detached instance

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm making a simple api where I can store images and do crud functionality on them. To communicate with the database I use Hibernate. While getting data is going fine, I can't add or delete data. This will result in this exception for the add;

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

and this exception for the delete;

> Removing a detached instance com.mycompany.server.model.Image#0

I have no clue why it can't do the job. It has worked before and I changed nothing to it. Hopefully you can find what is wrong. If this information isn't sufficient, just comment what you would like to see.

Here you have the model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Image.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Image i")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Image.findByImageId", query = "SELECT i FROM Image i WHERE i.imageId = :imageId")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Image.findByContenttype", query = "SELECT i FROM Image i WHERE i.contenttype = :contenttype")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Image.findByName", query = "SELECT i FROM Image i WHERE i.name = :name")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Image.findByDescription", query = "SELECT i FROM Image i WHERE i.description = :description")})
public class Image implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "image_id")
    private Integer imageId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 16777215)
    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "contenttype")
    private String contenttype;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public Image() {
    }

    public Image(Integer imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public Image(Integer imageId, String content, String contenttype, String name) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.content = content;
        this.contenttype = contenttype;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(Integer imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContenttype() {
        return contenttype;
    }

    public void setContenttype(String contenttype) {
        this.contenttype = contenttype;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (imageId != null ? imageId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Image)) {
            return false;
        }
        Image other = (Image) object;
        if ((this.imageId == null && other.imageId != null) || (this.imageId != null && !this.imageId.equals(other.imageId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.mycompany.server.model.Image[ imageId=" + imageId + " ]";
    }

}
```

And the Service Implementation:

```
public class ImageRepositoryServiceImpl implements ImageRepositoryService    {

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private static ImageRepositoryServiceImpl instance;

    private ImageRepositoryServiceImpl() {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.mycompany_server_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");
    }

    static {
        instance = new ImageRepositoryServiceImpl();
    }

    private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static ImageRepositoryService getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Image> getAllImages() {
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
       List<Image> images = em.createNamedQuery("Image.findAll", Image.class).getResultList();
        em.close();
        return images;
    }

    @Override
    public Image getImageFromId(int imageId) {
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        Image image = em.find(Image.class, imageId);
        em.close();        
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addImage(Image image) {
        try{
            EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(image);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();        
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
    }              
}

    @Override
    public boolean editImage(Image image) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet. edit"); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean DeleteImage(Image image) {
        try{
            EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            em.remove(image);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

I sovled the adding. Apparently the `image_id` wasn't auto incemented. Now I changed to ai and it works fine. The delete is still not working though :'(

Answer (score 1):

What issues I see in this code:

1. You misuse the entity manager. Each entity should belong to one entity manager. If you load entity using one entity manager and then save it using another entity manager you can get errors such as *Removing a detached instance com.mycompany.server.model.Image#0*.
2. You call *close* for entity manager only if there is no exceptions. If exception will rise before call of *close* you will get a leak of resources. Try to use try-with-resources.
3. You implemented equals and heshCode for entity based on generated identifier. It is bad practice. If you don't have other equality criteria for Image - do not override *equals* and *hashCode*.

Maybe this notes will help you.

Comment: I did the first thing that you suggested but still getting the Removing a detached instance com.mycompany.server.model.Image#0.

Comment: After trying your first solution for a second time it does work now:P thanks for the tips!